# Partition list into equal sums

Tags: list

How do I create a function that splits a list into n parts and each part has an equal sum. The function can also tell whether or not this is possible.

for example: [1,2,2,1,3,1] can be split into [[1,2,2],[1,3,1]].
[1,1,3,1,4,5,5] cannot be split so the function will return false

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is any simple way to do this, but it would be important to know if n is variable, or a requested function parameter. Also, I believe that the samples are incorrect, as [1,1,3,1,4,5,5] can be split into 4 parts [5],[5],[4,1],[3,1,1].

However, you could employ a few techniques to determine if it's possible to split based on the total sum of the list and the maximum number within the list. Taking the [1,1,3,1,4,5,5] list as an example, this sums to 20 in total. So in order for any split to be possible, you know the max would have to be less than or equal to half of the total sum. So if an element was 11, you know it's impossible.

Another check you can do if you know the number of lists you are meaning to split into, you could check for divisibility. Because the list sums to 20, and we know the max has to be <= 10. You can check divisibility of goal number of lists, if n is 3, 20/3 = 6.66, which is not possible given the list items being integer. If you don't know n, you can at least determine the number of lists that could be generated. 20/10 => 2 lists, 20/9 => false, 20/8 => false, ... , 20/5 => 4 lists, 20/4 => 5 lists, ... , 20=>2 = 10 lists.

Using both of these together, you can eliminate lists where the maximum number is higher than the goal sum per list. If you are trying to make 4 lists for instance, we know that means our goal sum is 5 (20/5 => 4 or 20/4 = 5), and our maximum number in the list is 6, we can immediately rule that this number of generated lists is impossible.

If you determine that there is a number of lists that is potentially feasible. Such as 2 lists, each summing to 10. I'm not sure the best course of action to fill the lists and try all possible combinations to see if you can make the sum. Potentially, the largest numbers in your list will be the most problematic, as they can be combined with the fewest number of other members to make the sum. So I believe the best course of action would be to try and fill from the largest numbers first, if you sort your input from small to large, that could be beneficial. The reason to start big and work small, is that if our goal is 5, and our list is [1,1,3,1,4,5,5]. We know that the 5 is already filling capacity and can be sent into it's own list and remove it from the input. When we get to 4, we know it can only be combined with a 1 to reach 5 (goal-curr = remainder => 5-4 = 1). If we don't have any, then we can cancel there and try a new n, or return false if there is no other n to test. Reaching 3 we know we are looking for 2 (goal-curr = remainder => 5-3 = 2). We look for the largest and work down taking a two if there is one, and taking the maximum number below 2 if there isn't a 2 supplied. This whole process would have to be "kind of" recursive in which we constantly are updating our current value, and the value that we are searching for.

Using this technique of taking the largest possible that will fit and always working from the smallest number of lists possible seems to work well in the few hand-written tests that I have done. Please let me know if this technique or any I have listed here are helpful. If there is a simpler way to do this, I would be very much interested!